# LOH benchmarking using benchmarkdotnet

Tags: c#, large-object-heap, benchmarkdotnet

So I'm doing some benchmark to compare the deserialisation of a big JSON file from a String or a Stream using the BenchMarkDotNet library. I'd like to see the state of the LOH specifically but I can't find how to do it.

Currently I'm having the followings, using the "MemoryDiagnoser" argument.

[image]

Is there a way to also benchmark the LOH ?

Comment: Click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/issues) to ask for features.  Or, since it is open source, implement it yourself and submit the patch.

Answer (score 3):

BenchmarkDotNet does not provide any extra information about LOH (there is simply no managed API that we could easily use to add any meaningful information).

[This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/maoni/2016/05/31/large-object-heap-uncovered-from-an-old-msdn-article/) old MSDN article by Maoni Stephens explains how to get some more information.

If you just want to get the size of LOH you can use `Performance Monitor` which is part of Windows OS.

Comment: I'm trying to use Perfmon but I'm running into an issue, not sure if this is related to BenchmarkDotNet or not ; when running the method that should generate huge LOH, the LOH in Perfmon doesn't move at all. Hovewer if I make some calls to this function outside of the benchmark, I notice an augmentation of the LOH. Could it be related to the GC calls between benchmarks that would make the allocation/collection too fast to be detected ? (Dunno if this is a stupid question or not... little bit lost here)

Comment: You are most probably looking at the parent process (what you run from the console), which does not run the benchmark. BenchmarkDotNet generates, builds and runs a new executable for every benchmark. You can either create a simple console app with the code that you want to profile or implement custom `IDiagonoser` and do it with BenchmarkDotNet.